# Formatting of drop down date selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am tweeking the rails getting started tutorial and try to add a drop down menu for each date element: day, month and year.
My HTML is perfect yet no value is passed to the CREATE action of the controller

Here is my code

```
<p>
<%= f.label :start %><br>
<%= select_day(Date.today) %>
<%= select_month(Date.today) %>
<%= select_year(Date.today, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => 5.years.from_now.year) %>
</p>
```

The field in the model is named start.
I recon I dont pass the value to the controller but I have no clue how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need a name for each of your dropdown:

```
<%= select_day(Date.today, {}, name: 'start_day') %>
<%= select_month(Date.today, {}, name: 'start_month') %>
<%= select_year(Date.today, { :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => 5.years.from_now.year }, name: 'start_year' ) %>
```

Then you need to handle this in your controller:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_start, only: :create

  # your actions

  private

  def set_start
    params[:your_model][:start] = "#{params[:start_year]}/#{params[:start_month]}/#{params[:start_day]}"
  end      
end
```

Have fun!

Comment: Many thanks, I have now some data, but unfortunately empty. The result is : "start"=>"//" I made sure I had a date input in the form. One more question: why defining set_start as private ? Can i not put the concatenation code inside the def_start function directly on the CREATE action ?

Comment: ouch, my mistake, I forgot brackets in the erb file. (not very used wih the form helpers). Seems Perfect now, thanks :)  Can I yet get rid of the private function, and add it directly within the CREATE action ?